# Laravel 6.x Page Expired after inserting StartSession in Kernel's middleware

Tags: php, laravel, constructor, laravel-6.2

I need to send some values to my Controller's constructor via Session, by default Session is not available on the constructor unless you insert this 2 lines in the Kernel's middleware block:

```
\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
\Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
```

The problem is that after I place those lines I get a **419 | Page Expired** message on my view.

Here is how my Kernel looks:

```
protected $middleware = [
    \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,

    \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
    \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
];   

protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    ],

    'api' => [
        'throttle:60,1',
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    ],
];
```

Comment: Could you try to run ```php artisan cache:clear```?

Comment: If you are getting this error in the form it is a csrf error.

Comment: @NguyenHungThai I did it and still not working

Comment: @ÖzgürCanKaragöz I have it:
** @csrf() **

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know what was the problem so I had to install a new Laravel project and now its working.